Is it humane/ethical to buy coral in the United States?
Sorry if this a weird question. Feel free to move to a different site if best posted elsewhere!
I read that most(?) coral in the US and live rocks are farmed from the ocean. Are they ethically sourced? Can I sleep at night knowing my coral tank didn't help support any environmentally devastating initiatives?

I think it depends.  Where do you get your coral from?  Big chains in the USA use aquaculture:  https://corporate.petco.com/Industry-Leading-Animal-Care

you might find some answers if you do a search here https://pets.stackexchange.com/ and here https://biology.stackexchange.com/

The US contribution to climate change will cause far far far more damage to corals than extracting it for the pet market.
